# Optional params[] array being named, can i do this?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

Here is my logging signature

```
public static void Debug(string message,Exception exception = null,object model = null,object userId = null,[CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",params object[] formatParams)
```

and I am trying to use it say like

```
Logger.Debug("My message: {0} {1}", formatParams:1,2)
```

How can i do this? I cannot find it on the net, I hope this is possible. I tried an anon type but didnt work.

```
Logger.Debug("My message: {0} {1}", formatParams: new{1,2})
```

Resolution:
I ended up using the example below. I was getting different errors with any other syntax so wanted to make sure this was saved here.

```
Logger.Debug("My message: {0} {1} {2}", formatParams: new object[] { 1, "string", 123.12m });
```

Edit:
My issue I was having ended up being related to a dynamic being passed in the formatParams, I fixed this by casting it to the type it actually was before logging it.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was having a hard time locating anything so all the more resources the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just have to call it with an array like this:

```
Logger.Debug("My message: {0} {1}", formatParams: new object[] { 1, 2 });
```

For a single parameter, this isn't necessary, you can just use:

```
Logger.Debug("My message: {0}", formatParams: 1);
```

Note that in many cases, you can also use an implicitly typed array:

```
Logger.Debug("My message: {0} {1}", formatParams: new[] { 1, 2 });
```

However, this will pass an array of objects which *contains* a single array of integers. The parameter value would look actually like this:

```
new object[] { new int[] { 1, 2 } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, the 1st one works, the second one complains about passing an int for an obj array, the 3rd one was throwing type issues also, the 4th one makes sense. I have started using the 1st example thanks for the good info!

Comment: @Tony Well, they should all work for as far calling your method (i.e. if your method was completely empty, it won't complain at all). It all depends on how your method *interprets* the arguments being passed in. It just goes to show, you need to be somewhat careful with this kind of parameter passing.

Comment: I found out what the issue was that I was having. The variable I was passing in was actually a dynamic, apparently that is not valid, to get around this I just had to cast the dynamic to the object it ended up being before logging. Lucky for me it was just an int and not really all that dynamic. Thanks for the help!